# SQL CORRELATION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID) AS  NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS 
FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID=ACCOUNT.ID 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT ON LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ID = CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID
WHERE Convert(datetime, convert(char(10), [CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT].CREATED_ON, 101)) BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-05-1'
  AND CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.DELETED!='1' 
  AND ACCOUNT.DELETED !='1'and  LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ACCOUNT_STATUS='1'
```

I get this error:

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>     The objects "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT" and "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Not sure how to solve - any ideas?

Comment: From the answer(s) aliasing will solve your problem.  Remember to be consistent across queries and stored procedures with aliases (for ex. call it `CA` in every place - it will make for much better maintanability.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just made a mistake in your SQL.  This line:

```
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT ON LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ID = CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID
```

Should probably be this?

```
INNER JOIN LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0 ON LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ID = CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID
```

Unless your intention was actually to do a self-join, in which case you would need to alias the table names (as others have mentioned)

Comment: that solves it...problem is why i get zero results since there should be records

Comment: +1 for the most logical solution... this make more sense (and is thus a more common mistake) than a self joining table, though it can be done (for example, think of a table of clients which self links to partner)

Comment: @Andreas - Hard to say why without knowing more about how your tables and data is structured.  Are you certain you are joining on the right fields?

Comment: Good job seeing through the syntax issue into the login issue :)

Answer (score 1):

you are specifying a table twice in your query 'CUSTOMER ACCOUNT' is used as the FROM as well as in an INNER JOIN.

If you change your query with aliases for the CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT tables you should be okay.

example:

```
FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT AS cust_acct

INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT as cust_acct_join
```

then when you reference the columns, be sure to use the alias you created

example:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT **cust_acct.**CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID) AS  NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT self joining. You need to alias at least one of them.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID) AS  NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS 
FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT CA1 INNER JOIN
    ACCOUNT ON CA1.ACCOUNT_ID=ACCOUNT.ID INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT CA2 ON LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ID = CA2.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID
WHERE
Convert(datetime,convert(char(10),[CA1].CREATED_ON,101)) 
BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-05-1'  AND  CA1.DELETED!='1' AND 
ACCOUNT.DELETED !='1'and  LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ACCOUNT_STATUS='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you self-join a table you have to use aliases:

```
SELECT … FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT AS C1 … CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT AS C2 …
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT t1.ID) AS  NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS 
FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT t1 INNER JOIN
ACCOUNT ON t1.ACCOUNT_ID=ACCOUNT.ID INNER JOIN
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT t2 ON LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ID = t2.ID
WHERE Convert(datetime,convert(char(10),t1.CREATED_ON,101)) 
BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-05-1'  AND  t1.DELETED!='1' AND 
ACCOUNT.DELETED !='1' and  LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ACCOUNT_STATUS='1'
```